# HDF5 viewers/editors linux

Tags: viewer, hdf5

[HDFVIEW](http://www.hdfgroup.org/hdf-java-html/hdfview/) is pretty good, but are there any alternatives?

It would be great to be able to change things like chunking/compression settings - hdfview doesn't have that functionality - without having to resort loading the files in using Java/python/whatever.

Comment: A list of software is available at https://support.hdfgroup.org/tools5desc.html

Comment: @lib Link is dead as of Dec 2017. Pretty sure this is the new path: https://support.hdfgroup.org/products/hdf5_tools/

Comment: Anyone still looking here, HDFCompass works very well for me (ubuntu 18.04) although it doesn't support editing: https://support.hdfgroup.org/projects/compass/ It's available in ubuntu software center.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can check out [vitables](http://vitables.org/). It can read both pytables and HDF5 formats.

Comment: Annoyingly, I can't get it to install as it requires python 2.7: The following packages have unmet dependencies.
  vitables: Depends: python (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2) but 2.6.5-0ubuntu1 is to be installed

Comment: vitables can edit group nodes. data in leaves can not be edit yet

Comment: Never a good sign when you have to build the documentation, and there's no documentation for how to build the documentation.  Especially for a user interface project.  And there are dependencies for building the documentation.

Comment: Seems quite outdated using `collections.Iterable` which is not working in new Python versions. When I fixed this had problems reading my h5 files claiming variable length strings are not supported yet. So it is not a good option.

Comment: Try `pip install hdf5view` use `hdf5view -f h5` AD2023.

Answer (score 4):

[Panoply](http://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/panoply/download/) has worked quite well for me in terms of visualization: it draws maps! Seeing the raw data... that's a bit harder.

[image: Panoply screenshot]